# Gif Image descriptor index

Tags: java, gif, javax.imageio

I have been reading a gif Image as an ImageInputStream using java.mageio.stream api. Is there a way I can parser that stream "manually" , in order to find the index position of the beginning of the image descriptor block?  According to the Gif documentation, the  Image Separator - which identifies  the beginning of an Image  Descriptor, the fixed value 0x2C. I have been reading each byte of the stream and matched it with the "0x2c" value, but obviously this is incorrect, as there are "attributes" that are more than one byte values.
I am trying to do this manually, as I am trying to avoid loading the whole image at this point.
Any ideas would be more than welcomed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure why you want to get at this, but it's certainly doable, if you know the GIF format and the structures it uses to store data. Read http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt. Simply searching for `0x2c` won't work.

Comment: PS: Why not use `ImageIO` and `ImageReader.getImageMetadata()`? It will give you most info without reading the image. Is there any specific information from the GIF you need that you can't get from that? You still haven't said *why* you want to read the Image Descriptor.

Comment: @haraldH Basically I need to get the correct image height and  width. I ended up using the ImageReader.getHeight() and ImageReader.getWidth() methods, which according to the documentation reads only the necessary info from the Image inputStream. I will try your suggestions also Thanks.

Comment: If I knew that was what you wanted, I'd suggested just using the `ImageReader.getWidth(..)/getHeight(..)`. Stick with that. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to provide an answer, so we can mark it as answered:

Instead of manually parsing the GIF structure, the easiest way of getting the data from the GIF image descriptor in Java is using ImageIO.

For simple values like image width and height, you can use the corresponding methods on `ImageReader` like this:

```
ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(gif); // gif is File or InputStream
ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).next();
reader.setInput(stream);
int w = reader.getWidth(0);
int h = reader.getHeight(0);
```

For more information on the GIF, you can use:

```
IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0);
```

For native metadata format, see [GIF metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/gif_metadata.html), for standard (format neutral) metadata format, see [standard metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/standard_metadata.html).